# Border length smaller than div width?

Tags: html, css

I have following code

```css
div {
   width: 200px;
   border-bottom: 1px solid magenta;
   height: 50px;   
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

The div width is 200px so border-bottom is also 200px but what should I do if I want border-bottom only 100px without changing div width?

Comment: You could set the margin-left and margin-right. That will change the border because the border won't cover the margin areas.

Answer (score 295, accepted):

You can use pseudoelements. E.g.

```css
div {
  width   : 200px;
  height  : 50px;   
  position: relative;
  z-index : 1;
  background: #eee;
}

div:before {
  content : "";
  position: absolute;
  left    : 0;
  bottom  : 0;
  height  : 1px;
  width   : 50%;  /* or 100px */
  border-bottom:1px solid magenta;
}
```

```html
<div>Item 1</div>
<div>Item 2</div>
```

No need to use extra markup for presentational purpose. :after is also supported from IE8.

edit:

if you need a right-aligned border, just change `left: 0` with `right: 0`

if you need a center-aligned border just simply set `left: 50px;`

Comment: This was my technique too, but note that it will give the border on the left half of the div. If you want it centred, give the `div:before` `left: 50px`.

Comment: The question doesn't specify in which position the border should appear so I haven't considered other positions

Comment: if the width of the bottom border is 50% and you want it centered, the style needs to be ```left: 25%``` since it will be 25% + 50% + 25%

Comment: @skift in this example 50px; is fine. the div is 200px wide. 50px = 25%

Comment: Yes I am aware in this example it works. But for others doing something similar that might trying to be making it responsive, you may need to use % as was that case I needed the answer for.

Comment: To center the border the best way for me is to set `right: 0` in `div:before`.
@fcalderan, do you usually use that indentation in your CSS?

Comment: for dynamic length of div instead of 200px, you may use margin:auto along with left:0 and right:0 for pseudo :after

Comment: This technique worked well for me. I wanted a common margin on both sides, so I just did left: 15%; right: 15% and no width or height at all and it worked beautifully.

Comment: Use `margin: auto`, `right: 0`, `left: 0` on the `:before` to center the line. Upvote if this helped you.

Answer (score 60):

Another way to do this (in modern browsers) is with a negative spread box-shadow.  Check out this updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/WuZat/290/

```
box-shadow: 0px 24px 3px -24px magenta;
```

I think the safest and most compatible way is the accepted answer above, though. Just thought I'd share another technique.

Answer (score 19):

I added line under under h3 tag like this

```html
    <h3 class="home_title">Your title here</h3>
```

```css
    .home_title{
        display:block;
    }
    .home_title::after {
        display:block;
        clear:both;
        content : "";
        position: relative;
        left    : 0;
        bottom  : 0;
        max-width:250px;
        height  : 1px;
        width   : 50%;  /* or 100px */
        border-bottom:1px solid #e2000f;
        margin:0 auto;
        padding:4px 0px;
    }
```

Answer (score 10):

You can use a linear gradient:

```css
div {
    width:100px;
    height:50px;
    display:block;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #000 1px, rgba(255,255,255,0) 1px), linear-gradient(to left, #000 0.1rem, rgba(255,255,255,0) 1px);
 background-position: bottom;
 background-size: 100% 25px;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
    border-top: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: I liked this solution the best, i don't like div / positioning before and after, this one felt like a more natural solution to me.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot have a different sized border than the div itself.

the solution would be to just add another div under neath, centered or absolute positioned, with the desired 1pixel border and only 1pixel in height.

http://jsfiddle.net/WuZat/3/

I left the original border in so you can see the width, and have two examples -- one with 100 width, and the other with 100 width centered. Delete the one you dont wish to use.

Answer (score 3):

Late to the party but for anyone who wants to make 2 borders (on the bottom and right in my case) you can use the technique in the accepted answer and add an :after psuedo-element for the second line then just change the properties like so:
http://jsfiddle.net/oeaL9fsm/

```
div
{
  width:500px;
  height:500px;   
  position: relative;
  z-index : 1;
}
div:before {
  content : "";
  position: absolute;
  left    : 25%;
  bottom  : 0;
  height  : 1px;
  width   : 50%;
  border-bottom:1px solid magenta;
}
div:after {
  content : "";
  position: absolute;
  right    : 0;
  bottom  : 25%;
  height  : 50%;
  width   : 1px;
  border-right:1px solid magenta;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I did something like this in my project. I would like to share it here. You can add another div as a child and give it a border with small width and place it left, centre or right with usual CSS

HTML code:

```
    <div>
        content 
        <div class ="ac-brdr"></div>
    </div>
```

CSS as below:

```
   .active {
    color: magneta;
  }
   .active .ac-brdr {
        width: 20px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        border-bottom: 1px solid magneta;
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
div{
    font-size: 25px;
    line-height: 27px;
    display:inline-block;
    width:200px;
    text-align:center;
}

div::after {
    background: #f1991b none repeat scroll 0 0;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    height: 3px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    width: 100px;
    margin:auto;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This will help:

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_hr_width.asp

```
<hr width="50%">
```

This creates a horizontal line with a width of 50%, you would need to create/modify the class if you would like to edit the style.

Comment: this is not helpful. the requirement is border of div

Answer (score 2):

I have case to have some bottom border between pictures in div container and the best one line code was -  **border-bottom-style: inset;**

Answer (score 1):

The border is given the whole html element. If you want half bottom border, you can wrap it with some other identifiable block like span.

HTML code:

```
<div> <span>content here </span></div>
```

CSS as below:

```
 div{
    width:200px;
    height:50px;   
    }
 span{
        width:100px;
        border-bottom:1px solid magenta;   
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I just accomplished the opposite of this using `:after` and `::after` because I needed to make my bottom border exactly `1.3rem` wider:

My element got super deformed when I used `:before` and `:after` at the same time because the elements are horizontally aligned with `display: flex`, `flex-direction: row` and `align-items: center`.

You could use this for making something wider or narrower, or probably any mathematical dimension mods:

```
a.nav_link-active {
  color: $e1-red;
  margin-top: 3.7rem;
}
a.nav_link-active:visited {
  color: $e1-red;
}
a.nav_link-active:after {
  content: '';
  margin-top: 3.3rem;      // margin and height should
  height: 0.4rem;          // add up to active link margin
  background: $e1-red;
  margin-left: -$nav-spacer-margin;
  display: block;
}
a.nav_link-active::after {
  content: '';
  margin-top: 3.3rem;      // margin and height should
  height: 0.4rem;          // add up to active link margin
  background: $e1-red;
  margin-right: -$nav-spacer-margin;
  display: block;
}
```

Sorry, this is `SCSS`, just multiply the numbers by 10 and change the variables with some normal values.

Answer (score 0):

**Border right length smaller than parent div
with pseudo-elements**

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway);

body{
 font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
}

 
div {
  width   : 200px;
  height  : 50px;   
  position: relative;
  z-index : 1;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  margin: 20px auto;
  padding: 20px;
  color:#726E97;
}

div:before {
  content : "";
  position: absolute;
  right    : 0;
  top     : 25%;
  height  : 50px;
  width   : 50%;
  border-right:5px solid #726E97;
}
```

```html
<div>BOX 1</div>
```