# Anyway to create border right that shorter than div height?

Tags: html, css, border

I have a box of social media content as below:

```
 1  |   2   |   3
```

anyway to make the "|" shorter then the div height?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `:after`, see this jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/mLycophq/2/
Your pipe is as high as your text in your `div` or you can change it by `font-size`.

```
div{
    height:20px;
    background-color:red;
    margin: 0 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
}

div:after{
    content: "|";
    color:black;
}
```

Or with a `border` property.

```
div:after{
    content: "";
    color:black;
    border-right:1px solid black;
    font-size: 10px;
}
```

Comment: I'm glad it worked. I know it isn't realy a border but it's the same principal.

Answer (score 1):

maybe try this, [Border length smaller than div width?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8572952/border-length-want-less-then-div-width)

```
div {
  width   : 200px;
  height  : 50px;   
  position: relative;
  z-index : 1;
}

div:before {
  content : "";
  position: absolute;
  left    : 0;
  bottom  : 0;
  height  : 50%;;
  width   : your width here  /* or 100px */
  border-bottom:1px solid magenta;
}
```

Comment: Its basicly the same only for the height

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this would be to set a small value for `line-height`

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/46qgb1hc/)**

### CSS

```
li {
    display: inline-block;
    border-right: 1px solid #111;
    padding: 0 8px;
    line-height: 4px; /* <-- here */
}
li:last-child {
    border:none;
}
```

Note:

1) This won't work if you need to set a fixed height on your element.

2) Technically, this method reduces the height of the element as well. But the end effect

is achieved because the font-size of the text determines the height of the text not the line-height

Comment: This doesn't work when you specify a height on your `li` so you should watch out for this.

Comment: @TeeDeJee, thanks that's true, I just pointed out an additional way to do this. Note that the question doesn't require the `li` having a height.... in any case I'll make a note of this.

Comment: This is a bad idea - if the text ever needs to wrap it will have overlapping line heights.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an ordered or unordered list then you could just set the padding for the `ul` `ol` to be larger than the padding for the `li`s. I did this for a similar problem and it helped me. Hope this helps. Make sure that your `li`s are where you assign the border property.