# Border-bottom length smaller than border-right?

Tags: html, css

how to do the Border-bottom length smaller than border-right?

```
img {
    border-bottom: 5px solid #02a8d8;
    border-right:1px solid  rgb(102, 102, 102);
    padding-right: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Seems to be working just fine for me https://jsfiddle.net/6kuaqxpd/1/

Comment: it works fine with me

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4131490/any-way-to-limit-border-length and/or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8572952/border-length-smaller-than-div-width

Comment: I want the border-bottom to be shorter, not coming together with border-right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use [`:after`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements) and set width that you want your `border-bottom` to have and then position it with `position: absolute` to `bottom: 0`. Something like this

```css
.image {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: none;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.image img {
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
}

.image:after {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 60%;
  border-top: 1px solid black;
  content: "";
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="image">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/350x160">
</div>
```