# Structuring div elements under text (HTML/CSS)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have designs which have a blue bar underneath text as a theme, such as the images below

[image]

[image]

I have currently been structuring my html like this for these bars:

```
 <div class="Header">
      <h4>My Website</h4>
      <div class="YBlock2"></div>
 </div>
```

Where the CSS class is defined as

```
.YBlock2{
background-color:blue;
width: 50px;
height: 10px;
}
```

However, I have been wondering if this is the best way to do this. It looks great on my computer, but I do not know if it is the best practice to use when aiming for the site to be used on a variety of different screen sizes and devices, or the best way in general.

Comment: similar thread : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8572952/border-length-smaller-than-div-width

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [pseudo-elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements) as `:after`.

```css
h4:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  margin-top: 3px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<h4>My website</h4>
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably a pseudo element is best, but for fun you could also do this.

```css
h1 {
  max-width: 50px;
  border-bottom: 3px solid blue;
  overflow-x: visible;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<h1>Bananas are pretty tasty</h1>
<p>So are pears</p>
```