# Small border under li / navigation element

Tags: html, css

This is what I am trying to achieve but it cannot figure it out:

[image]

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
li {
  height: 50px;
  width: 180px;
  line-height: 50px;
  background: #ddd;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}
li:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 5px 0 0 gold;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Hello</li>
  <li>World</li>
</ul>
```

I am just trying to get it like the pic above.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Border length smaller than div width?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8572952/border-length-smaller-than-div-width)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `pseudo elements`

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
li {
  height: 50px;
  width: 180px;
  line-height: 50px;
  background: #ddd;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  position:relative;
}
li:hover:after {
    content: '';
    border-bottom: 5px solid gold;
    width: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: calc(50% - 25px); /* This will make border center aligned */
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Hello</li>
  <li>World</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Abhishek I have marked yours as the answer :)

Comment: Happy to help :)

Answer (score 5):

I would use an after element for that little line

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0.75em 1.5em;             /* I would use padding instead of fixed width and height */
  text-transform: uppercase;    /* make text uppercase */
  position: relative;
}

li:hover {
  color: green;      /* change this to your green color */
}

li:hover:after {
  content:''; 
  display:block; 
  position:absolute;  /* position this at the bottom */
  bottom:0;
  left:35%;            /* left and right determine length of line, the longer you want it, the closer to 0 these values should be */
  right:35%;
  height:2px;
  background:green;    /* match the font color */
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Hello</li>
  <li>World</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Pete :)

Answer (score 2):

Change Css Like

```
li {
  height: 50px;
  width: 180px;
  line-height: 50px;
  background: #ddd;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  position:relative; /*add This Property*/
}

li:hover:after {
content:"";
position:absolute;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 0 0 gold;
  width:30px;
  left:50%;
  bottom:0px;
  height:10px;
  margin-left:-15px;
}
```

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
li {
  height: 50px;
  width: 180px;
  line-height: 50px;
  background: #ddd;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  position:relative
}
li:hover:after {
content:"";
position:absolute;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 0 0 gold;
  width:30px;
  left:50%;
  bottom:0px;
  height:10px;
  margin-left:-15px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Hello</li>
  <li>World</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hey Lalji, Thank you for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

You can add a pseude element like this:

CSS
`ul li{position:relative;}

ul li:hover::after{content:"";position:absolute;height:1px;width:25px;background-color:gold;bottom:0;left:50%;transform:TranslateX(-50%);}`