# TH bottom border should show half. How?

Tags: html, css

I am using HTML - Table and using border style attribute to apply border(border: 1px solid black).

My requirement is: Every th in table, bottom border show only half. Like `|tex__|`.

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/4n8gvsLm/20/) is the link to my code in jsfiddle.

Here is the code that I used:

```css
th, td {
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
      <th>Month</th>
   <td>January</td>
      <td>Feb</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <th>Salary</th>
   <td>$100</td>
      <td>$200</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

How can I do this?

Comment: may be you can use gradient for border

Comment: Show your HTML and CSS, much better using SO snippet.

Comment: Try to share your code, so we can help you better

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Border length smaller than div width?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8572952/border-length-smaller-than-div-width)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will use `:after` to achieve.

```css
th {
  position: relative;
}
th:after {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 1px;
  background-color: #000;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>AAAAAAAA</th>
      <th>BBBBBBBB</th>
      <th>CCCCCCCC</th>
      <th>DDDDDDDD</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Extending the Chaska's answer

```css
th {
  position: relative;
  border:1px solid #000;
  border-bottom:0px;
 }
th:after {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 50%;
  height: 1px;
  background-color: #000;
}
```

```html
<table cellspacing="0">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>text</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```